# Consider the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x) = 2x$. As a set of pairs, this can be described by

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, relations

Exercise 7: Consider the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x) = 2x$. As a set of pairs, this can be described by

$$\{\ldots,(-2,-4), (-1,-2), (0,0), (1,2), (2,4),\ldots\}.$$

If we simply switch the inputs with outputs:

a) Is the result a function?

b) Is the result a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?

My solution is part a):

No this is not the solution of the function it is the solution of function $Z=x/2$

My solution of part b):

(No this is the relation of $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$)

**(Can you pls check my solutions of above part)?**

And now I'm confused on second part

Let $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x) = 2x$.

a) Find function $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_\mathbb{Z}$.

b) Show that the function from a) does not satisfy $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

A corrected awnser to the first part:

a: This result is indeed a function $g: \{2z: z\in\mathbb{Z}\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$
because it only ever takes in even numbers.
So the awnser to b is No, because the domain is not the same as $\mathbb{Z}$

Tip: you can use LaTeX notation in asking a question.

EDIT:
Sorry I read the question incorrectly. Here is the awnser to the second part:

a: The anwser is the function 
$$g:\{2z:z\in\mathbb{Z}\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$$
$$2z\longmapsto z$$
because for any $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ it follows that:
$$(g\circ f)(z)=g(f(z))=g(2z)=z$$

b: The function $f\circ g$ has a domain of $\{2z:z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ so it can never be the identity on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm confused, which part did you answered?

Comment: I edited the question, is it better now?

Comment: I'm sorry: I edited my answer, is it better now?